# Retrieving the PHP response in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url() ?>/welcome/getall_images",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {id: '50'},
    success: function(data) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(data); 
        alert(obj.value); // not getting anything
    }
});
```

Through the above code i have retrieved the images from the db, and the following is the array of result from my controller :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 153
            [file_name] => DSC00081.JPG

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 154
            [file_name] => DSC00082.JPG

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 155
            [file_name] => DSC00083.JPG

        )

)
```

I want to give the filename which is retrieved through the `php response` to 
ajax success. I do not know what to be kept inside the `success`
I want to show the image inside the following. how should i do it..?

```
<img src="//the image from the php response" name="slide" border=0 width=300 height=375>
```

My php controller code is :

```
public function getall_images($id='')
{   //print_r($this->input->post('id'));

        $this->load->model('gallery_model');
        $data = $this->gallery_model->get_allimages($this->input->post('id')); //print_r($data);// I am getting the array in console
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the PHP code, and also check your browser console / dev tools to see if the request is a) being sent, b) getting a response c) what the response is.

Comment: what is  alert(obj.value);  ? check data variable

Comment: You haven't defined `obj` and you are trying to `alert(obj.value)`, try `alert(data)`

Comment: You would do it the same way, as if no AJAX was involved at all, and you just had to create an image element via JavaScript, or set the src of an existing one (and those are both things you should be able to easily research yourself.)

Comment: @JonStirling, While I Inspect in browser, i am getting as `This request has no response data available`..I added the php code now..!

Comment: @CBroe, how to do it that way..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line `<img src="//the image from the php response" name="slide" border=0 width=300 height=375>` with

```
<div id="resp_images"></div>
```

Change your controller code as

```
public function getall_images($id='')
{  
    $this->load->model('gallery_model');
    $data = $this->gallery_model->get_allimages($this->input->post('id')); 
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

In you ajax,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url() ?>/welcome/getall_images",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {id: '50'},
    success: function(data) { 
        if(data.length > 0)
        {
            var resp_images = '';
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                // alert(data[i].file_name);
                console.log(data[i].id);
                resp_images += '<img src="<?php site_url() ?>your_link/'+data[i].file_name+'" name="slide" border=0 width=300 height=375>';
            }
            $('#resp_images').html(resp_images);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the output it appears that the response is an array of objects. Your current code isn't working because you're attempting to call `$.parseJSON` on what will already be an object (hence this will cause an error). You're also trying to access a `value` property which does not exist, on a `obj` variable which you have not defined.

To get the image filenames from the AJAX response you instead need to loop through the array.  In that loop you can then `append()` the images to the DOM, setting the `src` as needed. Try this:

```
success: function(data) {
  var html = data.map(function(o) {
    return '<img src="' + o.file_name + '" />';
  }).join('');
  $('#container').append(html);
}
```

Note that I amended the HTML as both the `name` and `border` attributes were deprecated a long time ago on `img` elements. Also the `width` should be set in CSS.

Comment: `#container`..?

Comment: That's the element you want to append the `img` elements to. I simply used that as an example

Comment: I am not getting any response.. The following is my requirement. I am displaying a set of folders. while click of each folder, the set of images, for that folder are to be displayed in slideshow.

Comment: If you're not getting any response then it's possible the AJAX request is failing. Check the network tab of the console after making the request to check. I'd also suggest you start a new question about the issue if you find an error.

Comment: You helped me a lot..! I got an answer now through Deepak